# How do I earn credits to teach Chop new tricks?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-ifruit

In *iFruit's Chop the Dog*, the Grand Theft Auto V companion application, what are the different ways to quickly earn credits to teach Chop new tricks? Playing the various mini-games doesn't appear to be awarding any credits, and right now, waiting only seems to earn credits very slowly. Since you have to also spend credits to keep Chop happy and fed, I assume I must be missing some way to earn credits in large amounts.

Comment: My apologies. Did not realize this was an external app called `iFruit`, rather than an in-game app for an in-game `iFruit`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I've figured out:

The credits you can earn are pickup-items that show up in the mini games. They appear as gold coins with the letter "C" on them. They show up at random but it looks like you have to stay alive in the mini game for a while before they have a chance to appear.

[image: Screenshot]

- The Beach game is easiest to stay alive in, but I've also gotten a good amount of credits to show up in the Park game.
- The Street game is difficult and frustrating, and I haven't seen a gold coin there yet.
- If your goal is getting coins, don't worry about your score. Play the game just well enough to stay alive.
- Pick up the blue clocks to add time to the game. You have to stay alive long enough for the coins to show up.
- Pick up the "JUNK" soda cans for a speed boost. The boosts are stackable, so if you pick up multiple soda cans you can tear ass all over the level, increasing your chances to do whatever you need to stay alive.
- Avoid the beer bottles. These slow Chop down.
- The baggie of white drugs makes the screen wobble. I don't think it does anything else, so avoid it if you can.
- I don't know what the Sprunk cans or bottled waters do.
- Every time you play a minigame, Chop's water, food, and happiness meters go down. Make sure you save enough of the credits you win to keep him maintained.

If you have figured out anything I've missed, let me know.

Comment: Sprunk is just a short speed boost

Answer (score 1):

In game, once you get really low on credits (~40) it warns you and says that you must wait to generate credits and that you can also gain credits by taking Chop to the park. As for the mystical jackpot of jackpots, I have to say that I just started an hour ago but this is what I know.

Comment: Yes, but I've yet to have any of the walking activities yield a single credit after playing them. I'm not sure if it's due to me not getting gold or not though.

Comment: I have to talk him for a walk soon, I'll let you know if theres something there from getting gold. [Look here for some other information](http://gtaforums.com/topic/593102-ifruit-and-chop/)

Answer (score 0):

Keep playing, once you reach Gold it will start dropping coins. (You'll know when you see it, they're hard to miss).

Answer (score 0):

You get 20 credits per coin the beach is the easy way

Answer (score 0):

The beach is definitely the easiest way.  I've just received 80 credits in one game, even after missing some coins.  My poor little Chop was so thirsty.  Also, earning gold in each level gives you a nice gold collar for Chop.